# Auto-open DevTools for popups not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Auto-open DevTools for popups is a feature in den Dev tools of Chrome. 
I've checked this functionality in dev tools settings, but it just won't work.
Tried it with latest Chrome build (52), Canary and Chromium, same problem.

I've restarted Chrome, PC, tried it with opened Dev Tools and without.

Only thing which is working is to add the "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs" flag in the Chrome startup options.

Are there any known bugs about this? It is a little it annoying to add/remove the flag everytime.

Or any other ideas about this?

Thanks
Bene

Comment: That's for traditional "popups" opened via `window.open`

Comment: hm as I understood the request 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958

was intended to work for all new tabs...as in comment 87.. but whatever...thanks for the info

Comment: The bug you've linked is for the command line flag whereas the option in devtools is for `window.open` popups.

Comment: It is not working when creating content dynamically. It works when I call something like: window.open('someurl', ...). But not work when I call myWindow = window.open('', ...)